# Conversor multidivisas en PHP

Tags: php, php7, php5

Estoy tratando de crear un conversor de divisas que me conviertar x euros en las divisas de la eurozona.

El codigo fuente que tengo es este:

```
<?php
# Array que contiene las monedas locales con la equivalencia en el Euro:
$conversor = Array('ADF' => 6.55957, 'ADP' => 166.386, 'ATS' => 13.7603, 'BAM' => 1.95583, 'BEF' => 40.3399, 'CVE' => 110.265, 'CYP' => 0.585274, 'DEM' => 1.95583, 'EEK' => 15.6466, 'ESP' => 166.386, 'FIM' => 5.94573, 'FRF' => 6.55957, 'GRD' => 340.75, 'IEP' => 0.787564, 'ITL' => 1936.27, 'KMF' => 491.96775, 'LTL' => 3.4528, 'LUF' => 40.3399, 'LVL' => 0.702804, 'MCF' => 6.55957, 'MKD' => 1.95583, 'MTL' => 0.4293, 'NLG' => 2.20371, 'PTE' => 200.482, 'SIT' => 239.64, 'SKK' => 30.126, 'SML' => 1936.27, 'VAL' => 1936.27, 'XAF' => 655.957, 'XOF' => 655.957, 'XPF' => 119.3317);
# Nombre de las Divisas:
$nombre_moneda_local = Array('ADF' => 'Franco Andorrano', 'ADP' => 'Peseta Andorrana', 'ATS' => 'Chelin Austriaco', 'BEF' => 'Franco Belga', 'CVE' => 'Escudo Caboverdiano', 'CYP' => 'Libra Chipriota', 'DAM' => 'Marco Bosnio-Herzegovino', 'DEM' => 'Marco Aleman', 'EEK' => 'Corona Estonia', 'ESP' => 'Peseta Espanyola', 'FIM' => 'Marco Finlandes', 'FRF' => 'Franco Frances', 'GRD' => 'Dracma Griega', 'IEP' => 'Libra Irlandesa', 'ITL' => 'Lira Italiana', 'KMF' => 'Franco Comorense', 'LTL' => 'Litas Lituana', 'LUF' => 'Franco Luxemburgues', 'LVL' => 'Lats Leton', 'MCF' => 'Franco Monegasco', 'MKD' => 'Denar Macedonio', 'MTL' => 'Lira Maltesa', 'NLG' => 'Florin Neerlandes', 'PTE' => 'Escudo Portugues', 'SIT' => 'Tolar Esloveno', 'SKK' => 'Corona Eslovaca', 'SML' => 'Lira Sanmarinense', 'VAL' => 'Lira Vaticana', 'XAF' => 'Franco CFA de Africa Central', 'XOF' => 'Franco CFA de Africa Occidental', 'XPF' => 'Franco CFP Polinesia Francesa');
# Guardando en una variable la cantidad de divisas que hay:
$totaldivisas = count($conversor);
# Guardando en una variable la cantidad de divisas que hay para el bucle:
$totaldivisasb = $totaldivisas - 1;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $totaldivisasb; $i++)
{
    # Mostrando el nombre de las divisas iniciales:
    $nombremonedainicial = $nombre_moneda_local[$i];
    # Convertiendolo la divisa:
    $conversion_inicial = 500 * $conversor[$i];
    # Poniendo a dos decimales el resultado final, inicial y la conversion al euro:
    $mostrar_importe_total_euro = number_format((float)$conversion_inicial, 2, ',', '.');
    $mostrar_importe_total_inicial = number_format((float)500, 2, ',', '.');
    # Mostrando el resultado final:
    print "<p>$mostrar_importe_total_inicial euros son $mostrar_importe_total_euro $nombremonedainicial&hellip;</p>\n";
}
?>
```

A la hora de ejecutarlo, me da dos problemas:

Me indica en las lineas 13 y 15 varios undefined offset

Como podria corregir este tema.

Comment: Bueno... tu array no tiene índices numéricos, si no strings "ADF", "ADP" etc... Por qué luego intentas acceder al array usando índices numéricos?? Deberás usar las claves que tú le diste al montar el array.

Comment: Hola Benito, gracias por la indicacion, ya se como hare el replanteo de este problema.

Answer (score 1):

Como te dijeron en el comentario, ambos arrays no tienen índices numéricos, por lo que se deben recorrer de otra manera. Una forma fácil puede ser con `foreach`, solo hay que hacer 3 cambios:

```
<?php
// ...
foreach($conversor as $k=>$v)
{
    # Mostrando el nombre de las divisas iniciales:
    $nombremonedainicial = $nombre_moneda_local[$k];
    # Convertiendolo la divisa:
    $conversion_inicial = 500 * $v;
    // ... resto del codigo
}
```

Con eso ya se resuelve, pero en un programa real en producción hay que comprobar si el índice existe en el otro array, por ejemplo con `in_array()`, si no dará un error.

Comment: Gracias por la indicacion, aeportugal, ya hice la correcion con esto tambien.